Bold italicized text in mlmodern + \renewcommand\bfdefault{b}
I like the mlmodern font with non-extended b (\renewcommand\bfdefault{b}), but when I try to make italicized text bold in it, it switches to slanted bold text (for example, when I call \emph in \section{...}). This is inconsistent with unbolded \emph, which produces correct italicized text.
Is it possible to have italicized bold text in mlmodern + \renewcommand\bfdefault{b} which is aesthetically faithful to its regular bold counterpart? Merely switching to bold italics of lmodern is not a satisfactory solution for me.

Both bold (extended) italic and slanted are available, If you are not getting italic then that is due to code you have not shown.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mlmodern}

\begin{document}

xyz \textit{abc} italic

\textbf{xyz \textit{abc}} bold italic

xyz \textsl{abc} slanted

\textbf{xyz \textsl{abc}} bold slanted


\end{document}

The non extended b shape is only available in slanted according to the fd file.
The following produces
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/mlmr/b/it' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/mlmr/b/sl' tried instead on input line 11.


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mlmodern}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\bfdefault{b}

xyz \textit{abc} italic

\textbf{xyz \textit{abc}} bold italic

xyz \textsl{abc} slanted

\textbf{xyz \textsl{abc}} bold slanted


\end{document}


Sorry for neglecting to mention that I want to use italicized bold text in mlmodern alongside \renewcommand\bfdefault{b}. The edit is on its way. In any case, is there a trick to use non-extended b with italicized bold mlmodern text?

@Godbless you were lucky that I spotted that at all, your question should (always) have an example showing the problem.  the font designer chose not to make a font in that style so you need to choose a different font eg bold extended italic or stick to slanted or use a different family, or put in a feature request that a suitable font be made.

@Godbless do you want the extended bold italic rather than the bold slanted? you've edited, but you still haven't provided an example.

This is a modification of David's answer which substitutes extended bold italic rather than bold oblique for bold italic.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mlmodern}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\bfdefault{b}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{mlmr}{b}{it}
     {<->sub * mlmr/bx/it}{}

xyz \textit{abc} italic

\textbf{xyz \textit{abc}} bold italic

xyz \textsl{abc} slanted

\textbf{xyz \textsl{abc}} bold slanted


\end{document}


